# Npgsql.NpgsqlException: "ОШИБКА: 42601: ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: visual-studio, postgresql, postgresql9.5

Пользователь заполняет форму, где вводит значения в textBox-ы.

```
NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO 'Tip' (code_tip, 
name_tip) VALUES (@p1, @p2)", con);


com.Parameters.Add("code_tip", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint).Value = 
textBox1;
com.Parameters.Add("name_tip", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char, 40).Value = 
textBox2;

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

На этом моменте visual-studio выдает мне ошибку:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException: "ОШИБКА: 42601: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "'Tip'")"
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> INSERT INTO 'Tip'

По синтаксису (и стандарту SQL) `insert` запроса после ключевого слова `into` должно идти имя таблицы. Вы указали строковой литерал. Парсер соответственно удивляется и отвечает, что вы написали непонятно что.

- в одинарных кавычках `'Tip'` - строковой литерал.
- без кавычек `Tip` - имя объекта, принудительно приводимое парсером к нижнему регистру, т.е. `tip`
- в двойных кавычках `"Tip"` - регистрозависимое имя объекта

Если у вас таблица именно `Tip`, то единственным корректным способом к ней обращаться будут двойные кавычки:

```
INSERT INTO "Tip" ...
```

Comment: тогда он просто не запускается выдавая ошибки:
    Ошибка CS1729  'NpgsqlCommand" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 4.
    Ошибка CS0119 'Tip" является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте.
И еще требует зачем-то написать ",Tip,"

Comment: Tip это название таблицы

Comment: А это вопрос к вашему языку, а не к базе. Со стороны базы я могу ответить: нужен именно `"Tip"`, раз уж так умудрились назвать. Со стороны кода - вопрос к вам, как сделать именно нужный запрос. Может быть экранировать кавычки

Comment: Окей, это учту. Тогда получается так: NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO \"Tip\" (\"code_tip\", \"name_tip\") VALUES (@p1, @p2)", con); Но тогда он выдает ошибку: Npgsql.NpgsqlException: "ОШИБКА: 42703: столбец "p1" не существует". Да у меня не существует такого столбца, но я же после названия таблицы указываю столбцы. И тогда что нужно указывать тут? Я так понимаю, что это просто как переменная?

Comment: Посмотрите в логе СУБД, какой запрос та получила. Предполагаю, что если вы хотите использовать параметр с именем `p1`, то и добавлять надо параметр `p1`, а не `code_tip`. Или наоборот. Это так, экспромтом - вы же не назвали ни на каком языке у вас приложение, ни какой библиотекой доступа к базе пользуетесь. Это явно не `C` и `libpq`

Comment: windows form, C#, библиотек нет(если не считать Npgsql, но я не знаю что это). И я не знаю что такое лог, и где его смотреть в pg, ну или знаю но не понимаю. И насколько я знаю как строиться запрос, то у меня идет сперва название таблицы (колонки) и потом values(значения переменных, которые я получаю ниже). Если я тут тоже напишу название столбцов, то получаю ту же самую ошибку. Что тогда делать? Да и вообще что делать?